# Are Intel Xeon E5-4xxx generally compatable if a board supports E5-1xxx and E5-2xxx?

Tags: cpu, compatibility, hardware-rec, xeon

I have an [ASUS X99-M WS](https://www.asus.com/us/Commercial-Servers-Workstations/X99M_WS/overview/) motherboard that has a LGA2011-3 socket and explicitly supports a number of Xeon processors, including many in the E5-1xxx and E5-2xxx range (v3 and v4).

It seems that the first number of the Xeon E5s relate to the 'Maximum CPU Configuration' (1 vs 2 vs 4). Obviously I am only interested in using one CPU in the system, but I'm wondering if an E5-4xxx processor would be 'likely to work' on the board, or if it needs to be explicitly supported by the BIOS on the X99 board.

By 'likely to work', I mean 'worth spending $125 for a decent chance', not a guarantee of compatibility.

[ASUS X99-M WS - CPU QVL List](https://www.asus.com/us/Commercial-Servers-Workstations/X99M_WS/HelpDesk_CPU/)

[Xeon E5 v4 Family - Intel ARK](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/series/91287/intel-xeon-processor-e5-v4-family.html)

Comment: Do you have the latest bios from Asus installed?

Comment: I do, v4001. The v4s have were added in bios v3002.

Answer (score 0):

Is the E5 4XXX a V3 or V4? If the socket is correct, there is a good chance. But older versions, who knows. The Xeon documentation of Intel is very very bad. There are no safe information. If it does not work, just sent it back. If you cannot sent it back, do not risk buying it. Xeons are not as good of a value as it might seem. I made this mistake only once.

Intels of the last year waste a lot of power. Just rather use the money you will waste on power for a better CPU with less TDP at the same or better performance. This will run much much quiter amd in the summer be not as hot in the room. You will not regret a smarter buying choice.

Currently, you will get a just as fast CPU with **half** the TDP at the same price, also get ECC support and have PCIe 4. Also the resale value is much higher. Buying intel at this time just is not worth it, especially if you do not have an option to return it. My suggestion: Don't do this. It is not smart, if it even will work. You will also have no overclocking for Xeon. And 135W for the same performance as a 65W AMD CPU? Honestly? Also, same performance with fewer cores, which will result in a dramatical performance boost especially for single threaded applications (which most are, or use very few cores).

Comment: I'm looking at an $89 Xeon E5-4627v4 10 core 2.6 GHz (QS), and I already have the ASUS Motherboard with an 2011-3 socket. I'm mostly doing this as a hobby project in a 1U case. When I upgrade, it'll definitely be to a Ryzen and a board with ECC support.

Comment: That said - your thought is a E5-4xxx v4 would be likely to work in a board that lists E5-1xxx and E5-2xxx (v3 and v4) CPUs?

Comment: I have no idea, if this works. It in theory **could** work. But there is no way to say for certain. As already said: If you can return the chip, test it for yourself. If you cannot return it and value money quite a bit, you should not risk. I *guess* it could work for 20%. As stated, some intel processor worked on boards, that where not designed for that chip before in history. But I would never bet my life on it. Same socket + right to return the article = worth a try. It will very likely do no harm at least.